# Delphi - Catch all action.onexecute from an application

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I have a big application with hundreds of TActions. Each of them is used and implements different functionality needed.

It is possible to catch (hook) all the TAction.OnExecute from an application? Is there any windows message which I can hook so I can log the action name which was executed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add a [`TApplicationEvents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents) object and handle the [`OnActionExecute`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/AppEvnts.TApplicationEvents.OnActionExecute) event. The event handler is passed the `Action` instance and so can readily obtain the name of the action.

The `OnActionExecute` event will fire before the action's `OnExecute` event fires. You can even stop the action's `OnExecute` event from firing by setting the `Handled` parameter to `True` in your `OnActionExecute` event handler.

Comment: Just an FYI, the `TApplication.OnActionExecute` event is the second hook that processes a `TAction`.  If the `TAction` is associated with a `TActionList`, the `TActionList.OnExecute` event gets first dibs on the `TAction`.  If that event handler returns True, the `TApplication.OnActionExecute` event is NOT triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Based on David's answer I've made a small example:

```
program Project1;

uses
  ExceptionLog,
  Forms,
  Unit2 in 'Unit2.pas' {Form2},
  AppEvnts,
  Classes,
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

{$R *.res}

type TAppEventsHack = class
   procedure onAppEvtExec(Action:TBasicAction;var Handled:Boolean);
 end;

var aEvHack : TAppEventsHack;
    aAppEvents : TApplicationEvents;

{ TAppEventsHack }

procedure TAppEventsHack.onAppEvtExec(Action: TBasicAction;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   OutputDebugString(PAnsiChar(Action.Name));
   Handled := False;
end;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
 try
  aEvHack := TAppEventsHack.Create;
  aAppEvents := TApplicationEvents.Create(nil);
  aAppEvents.OnActionExecute := aEvHack.onAppEvtExec;

  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
 finally
  freeandnil(aEvHack);
  freeandnil(aAppEvents);
 end;
end.
```